# Arel complex query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

So i have the following tables

```
class Game
  belongs_to :player0, :class => "Player"
  belongs_to :player1, :class => "Player"
end

class Player
  belongs_to :user
end


class User
  #has a field called race
end
```

Now i need a query to do the following

Find all Games where player0.user.race is "x" and player1.user.race is "y" OR player0.user.race is "y" and player1.user.race is "x".

I just began using rails 3. I can easily write the query myself in sql, but i'd rather learn the arel way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [meta_where](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=meta_where&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=https://github.com/ernie/meta_where&ei=lxPKTviSNqeL4gSuv_g2&usg=AFQjCNFChgk5FFB5ij03RIYo_uXT4PGqLQ) gem:

```
Game.joins(:player0, :player1).where((:player0 => {:user => {:race => 'x'} | {:race => 'y'}}) | (:player1 => {:user => {:race => 'x'} | {:race => 'y'}}))
```

Check it by using `to_sql` method.

Comment: You should rather look at the squeel gem instead of meta_where as it will not be updated to work with Rails 3.1. Squeel is developed by the same developer and contains several of the same ideas... That is, unless you only want to use it to generate the sql once :-)

Comment: Awesome. Did not know about these gems. Thank you very much.